# Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in

Tags: php, mysqli

So i been here for a while i just cant solve the problem.
Thanks for the Help.

Donc je été ici pendant un moment, et j'arrive pas résoudre le problème.
Merci.

```
<?php

if (!$link = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "")) {
    echo "Connexion impossible à mysql";
    exit; }

if (!$db_selected=mysql_select_db("supersaiyandatabase", $link)) {
    echo "Sélection de base de données impossible";
    exit; }

?>
```

Comment: `mysql` != `mysqli`. Read the manual.

Comment: you're mixing the mysqli and mysql*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it a bit wrong, since you're setting $link to a new mysqli object, you have to select the db my doing this:

```
if (!$db_selected=$link->select_db("supersaiyandatabase")) {
    echo "Sélection de base de données impossible";
    exit; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, solved my problem!! Works now.

```
<?php

if (!$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","supersaiyandatabase")) {
    echo "Connexion impossible à mysql";
    exit;
}

?>
```